# How to bypass Bound Javascript OnChange Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `.js` File that bind several `OnChange Events` to my `Controls`.

Now i have a `function()` that is changing all of these `Controls`...

My Issue is that now all the `onchange events` are fireing...

**What options do I have around this , without `unbinding` everything all of my `onChange Functions`?**

*Sample Code*:

```
$('#Sections,#Sections2,#Sections3,#Sections,4').bind('change', function () {
    SomeAwesomeFunctionUnrelatedToTheOneBelow('CUSTOM');
});
```

Then later from another ( change function )

```
function SetText(name, value) {
    if (value != null)
        { $('#' + name).val(value); }
    else
        { $('#' + name).val(''); }
}
```

After this executres all 4 onchange functions are run ... i need a way around this.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: you want to make updates to the controls without having those updates fire `change` events? Is that right?

Comment: @lbstr yes this is correct!

Comment: @WannaCSharp there you go, don't understand why it was necessary but here you go :P

Comment: `val()` alone wouldn't trigger the `change()` event.

Comment: @haim770 I only used that as an example, I am changing radio buttons, textboxes, dropdowns, basically any and all controls on in my View.

Comment: @Pakk sorry, but I don't have time to give a good answer. But, add `event` as an argument to your `change` handler. Do a `console.log` on `event` and see how it is different when you change the inputs manually vs. programmatically. I've used this approach in the past with success.

Comment: i believe i checked `event.originalEvent`, which won't exist when you trigger the event programmatically. Could be wrong on that, so please confirm for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's **[Event Namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)** to mark each event with a namespace that will later let you un-bind (or trigger) only the `change` event of that specific namespace.

Binding:

```
// binding a 'change' event with 'ns1' namespace
$('#some_element').bind("change.ns1", function() { ... })

// binding a 'change' event with 'ns2' namespace
$('#some_element').bind("change.ns2", function() { ... })
```

Un-Binding:

```
// un-binding only the 'change' event with 'ns1' namespace
$('#some_element').unbind("change.ns1")

// un-binding only the 'change' event with 'ns2' namespace
$('#some_element').unbind("change.ns2")
```

Comment: I would prefer to NOT unbind. is there a way i can just disable all controls / not allowing the change functionality to run??